# Change coordinate in xarray dataset

Tags: python-xarray

Suppose I have a `Dataset` with a few coordinates and two of them, say `'x'` and `'y'`, are the same length. Now, if I have a variable in the `Dataset` that has many coordinates and `x` is one them, how can I change that coordinate to be `y` in an easy way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xarray's Dataset object has a built-in method to do exactly this: `Dataset.swap_dims`. The documentation is here: http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.swap_dims.html

In your case, with ds as your `Dataset`,

```
ds.swap_dims({'x': 'y'}, inplace=True)
```

will return your Dataset with the x and y dimensions swapped in all data variables.
Or if you want to keep your original Dataset,

```
ds_new = ds.swap_dims({'x', 'y'})
```

will store the `Dataset` with the dimensions swapped in `dataset_new` while leaving the original `Dataset` unchanged.